How to create Authentication object inside the @RabbitListener methods?
In my application there is a listener that operates with methods requiring Authentication from Spring Security and request information. Unfortunately, those methods do not have their authentication tokens during runtime and the requests are not bound to any thread so when RabbitMQ tries to send those requests the exception is thrown:
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.


That i what the run-as support is for, I also wonder how yu are calling this looks like you are using reques scoped beans. Please post the full stacktrace instead of just a snippet without information. \

What user should be used? Some technical user? Do you need user information in your method (username, roles)?

@dur User that should be used is the application itself. The thing is that those processes which are ran in different threads need to be authenticated, but there is no actual person sending the request

@АртёмСмирнов What application? The producer or the consumer? If you want to use the user of the consumer, how do you choose it? There are more than one authenticated user in the consumer, which one should be used?
